# getting base64 from google api images

Tags: image, api, google-api, base64

i'm using Google oAuth in my website to users log-in and share some photos from own google drive. right now, Google retrieves me a following kind link:

```
https://doc-0o-30-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/dpstkbb0rv4jmf62kb8dc9m8ijh53ocp/1hotfemebktd56o93gcoi76k89edbtjp/1512662400000/05170378500578169489/05170378500578169489/1MxIJ5EBLcIVtqxjGi_ZoYYqpw1UQHBiCRA?e=download&gd=true
```

**i've change this url to security reason**

the problem is i want get the base64 of this  image to save in specific folder related to the user but for some reason. using php function `file_get_contents();` it does not work.

i've try use  JS canvas to get with `img.toDataURL()` but it still fail.

there's some way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck on the same problem using **node.js** and npm package [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) (official package from google).

Although I'm late but it might help somebody else looking for a similar problem.

**Node.js**

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

//setup your oauth credentials and tokens

oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);

var drive = google.drive({
    version: 'v2',
    auth: oauth2Client
});

drive.files.get({
    fileId: fileId, //id of the file you are looking for
    alt: 'media'
}, {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    encoding: null
}, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);

        //handle the error
    } else {
        var imageType = response.headers['content-type'];
        var base64 = new Buffer(response.data, 'utf8').toString('base64');
        var dataURI = 'data:' + imageType + ';base64,' + base64;

        res.send(dataURI);
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="dataURI_received_from_above_HTTP_request"></img>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. to get contents in with google api, first,  we shoud set the correct scope. in this case, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`.

so, we should set in get_file_contents() the context passing the parameter "Authorization" with the access_token. so, the code will be:

```
    $context = stream_context_create(array(
            'http' => array(
                'header'  => "Authorization: Bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE]"
            )
        ));

   $conteudo = file_get_contents($urlImagem, false, $context);
```

This was my solution. i hope it help someone else.